# react google maps - Move data between functions

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-hooks

I have the example code of react-google-maps and it works great.
I'm now trying to create a page where the user can influence what is displayed on the map (some kind of filtering).

I have 2 functions that need to talk to each other, the code built this way:

```
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps"

function Map() {
 useEffect(() => {
    // Getting the data
}
 return (
<GoogleMap
      zoom={userLocation.zoom}
      center={{ lat: userLocation.lat, lng: userLocation.lng }}
    >
</GoogleMap>
)
```

Now that's where things get a little complicated:

```
const MapWrapped = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map))

export default function App() {
return (
     // user interface for filtering goes here!
    <MapWrapped
      googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=${''}`}
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    />
  </div>
)
}
```

I need to get data (useState) from the function Map to function App.
I can't find a way to do so.
I can't declare use state outside a function and if I put everything in one function the map just keeps reloading.

Comment: Have you included all relevant code? Where is an `useState` hook used?

Comment: I tried to remove everything not relevant to the question, currently the useState is inside the Map function but I can't access the hook when it's there.

Comment: The `Map` component can't access a `useState` hook declared inside it? Have you tried [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and passing it down to the `Map`|`MappedWrapped` component?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed a good night sleep:
Changed the map function to look like that:

```
const Map = ((props) => {
```

And now I'm able to get props from the App function.
Will declare the useStates on the App function and move the data that way